# Refresh DIV using Jquery copies whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want my PHP page to refresh specified DIV every 'n' second.

Code:

```
   <body>     
   <div id="refreshData">
   //Functions
   </div>
   <div id="setofDIV">
   //Functions
   </div>
   </body>
           <script type="text/javascript">             
                function show_data()
                   {
                    $('#refreshData').load('main.php);
                   }
               setInterval('show_data()', 5000);
            </script>
```

But after refresh whole body is copied twice in main.php file.

Comment: is main.php the file where this javascript is?

Comment: If `main.php` returns the entire page, then it's whole contents are rendered in this div again. `main.php` should render only the new contents for the div if the request is an AJAX request, or the JavaScript should be smart enough to extract the content from it and only use that part.

Comment: @GolezTrol Yes whole main.php is rendered into the #refreshData.How to overcome it?

Comment: You should be only loading in the data that is needed not the entire page, as that will as GolezTrol mentioned it will add the extra elements including the scripts. So each time your interval runs you are adding yet another interval. So after say 25 seconds you are going to have 32 intervals running

Comment: ok but give me exact way to overcome that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP solution**

To make this work, `main.php` will have to return only the contents of the div. That means it needs to detect when to render a whole page or just the div's contents. 
There are a couple of ways to do this.

1. Make a separate php file for the AJAX requests which always only
   returns that part of the page
2. Use the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header
   to detect an AJAX request

   if ( !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
        strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') 
   {
      // If you get here, this is an AJAX request. Make sure to only render the div's contents.
   }
3. Similar to one. Instead of making a separate PHP file, add a query string parameter, so the page
   will know that it should only return that part. You can even specify in the query string which part, so you can load different parts through the same php file in different intervals.

**JavaScript solution**

Alternatively, you can just fetch the entire page, and use jQuery to extract the div's content from it. The [load function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) already has a convenient syntax for this purpose.

> The .load() method, allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

The load function allows for an extra selector after the url, the content matching the selector is fetched from the AJAX response and inserted into the specified element in the document. For this reason, the ids should be different, otherwise you will insert an element with the same id inside the existing element, and that's not allowed.

So your HTML should look like this:

```
<div id="refreshDataContainer">
  <div id="refreshData">
  </div>
</div>
```

Once you've made that change, you can completely replace `#refreshData` with the following line:

```
$('#refreshDataContainer').load('main.php #refreshData');
```

Comment: Thank you for the information.But can you specify the code using AJAX as you specified in first method

Comment: `load()` already performs an AJAX request. The solution of method 1 is not to call `main.php`, but a different url which only returns the contents of the div. For instance `main_refreshdata.php`. Or (as in 3) you can call `main.php?part=refreshdata`, so main.php will know that is should only render the new content, not an entire page. Each of those three solutions require a change to the server side (PHP) code.

Comment: Judging your responses, you seem to have some problems understanding the PHP part, so I think the JavaScript solution might be the best for now. Fortunately the `load()` function already allows you to do this very easily. I've added an explanation to the answer to show you how.

Comment: Yes i tried but the #refreshData changes its position

Answer (score -1):

Try below :-

```
<div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'YOUR PHP page url',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".result").html(results);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,1000);
</script>
```

'YOUR PHP page url' should contain the content that you want to display on main page.

Comment: If YOUR PHP page url only returns that part, then there is no reason to use this alternative way of performing the request over the `load` method that OP was already using.

Comment: OP's current code is already doing this. jQuery's .load method is a shortcut to this type of code. OP's problem is that the page they are loading is the same page with the javascript so each of these calls adds another javascript that is going to load in the same thing over and over